# Cannot block the SharePoint website using Powershell Sharepoint online management shell

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am following the document [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices)

and trying to block a site for unmanaged devices using the command below:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<SharePoint online URL>/sites/<name of site or OneDrive account> -ConditionalAccessPolicy BlockAccess
```

But I am getting following errors:

> Set-SPOSite : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified
>   named parameters. At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-SPOSite -Identity https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/VerySecure -C ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of SPO Management Shell? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Answer (score 0):

I can run this command without error.

Install the latest version of SharePoint Online Management Shell as @Vladimir Herrlein suggests and then test again as a global administrator.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com -credential <admin account>

Set-SPOSite -Identity <siteURL> -ConditionalAccessPolicy BlockAccess
```

Comment: @Nlama Have you run the SharePoint Online Management Shell as Administrator?

Comment: yes, I am global administrator in my tenant

Comment: @Nlama Is this global Administrator also a site collection Administrator? Maybe try another site URL and see the result.

Comment: None of the above solution works, still having an issue with this. Created a several ticket and Microsoft team is not help me to fix this issue. 

Anyone out there also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-nowait` to the end and the command will execute.